# Combinatorial Optimization Algorithm Problem

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I have a problem whereby i need to find the optimum combination for a bunch of IO modules attached to a PLC. Each PLC will have a combination of analogue and digital inputs and outputs that it requires to pick up and there are different IO modules available with different combinations of analogue and digital inputs and outputs that I can attach to the PLC to pick them up. I was looking for an algorithm that would take the required IO count and then sorts through the various options available to output the optimum combinations of modules (or even just the possible combinations of modules) and then sort it via price of each one.

For example:

Panel 1 requires the following IO to be attached to it:

- Digital Inputs - 73
- Digital Outputs - 20
- Analogue Inputs - 37
- Analogue Outputs - 19

and the modules I can choose from might be:

- 8 Digital Input
- 4 Analogue Input 4 analogue output
- 4 Digital Input 4 Digital Output
- 24 Digital Input
- 8 Analogue inputs 12 Digital Inputs 12 digital Outputs 6 Analogue outputs
- 5 Analogue inputs 5 Digital Inputs 4 digital Outputs 4 Analogue outputs

I thought this might be something like the cutting stock problem however i have drawn a blank and i am not sure if i am going down a rabbit hole.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have tried a variation of 2 and 3 dimensional cutting stock algorithms however it doesn't give an optimum output

Answer (score 1):

You could write your constraints as a set of linear inequations:

```
D_i: 8*M_1         + 4*M_3 + 24*M_4 + 12*M_5 + 5*M_6 >= 73
D_o:                 4*M_3          + 12*M_5 + 4*M_6 >= 20
A_i:         4*M_2                  +  8*M_5 + 5*M_6 >= 37
A_o:         4*M_2                  +  6*M_5 + 4*M_6 >= 19
```

`M_i` is the number of modules of type `i`.

The optimization strives to minimize the sum of module costs:

```
Cost = P_1*M_1 + P_2*M_2 + P_3*M3 + P_4*M_4 + P_5*M_5 + P_6*M_6
```

`P_i` is the cost per module `i`

This system of ineqations together with the objective function can be solved by a designated *integer linear programming* solver like [CBC](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc). But other general purpose constraint programming solvers like [z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) or [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) are also capable of solving such systems.